# TinyMCE Remove Advanced tab from Tables dialog

Tags: tinymce

I dont want to see the advanced tab on the tables dialog, and I dont want to remove it from the source in case its overwritten with updates.

Note: not Wordpress.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

In TinyMCE v4, there are three plugin options: *table_advtab*, *table_row_advtab* and *table_cell_advtab*, that specify whether the Advanced Tab is enabled on the Table Properties, Row Properties and Cell Properties dialogs respectively.

So, if you want to hide the Advanced Tab for all table properties, you would set all of these options to false like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  table_advtab: false,
  table_row_advtab: false,
  table_cell_advtab: false
});
```

Reference for these options can be found here:
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/table/#table_advtab

Answer (score 0):

I have to tell you, that this is not possible. There are several settings concerning the table plugin, but not the one you are looking for.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, but I don't really want a 'setting' I'd be happy with some kind of filthy hack.

Comment: the other dirty option is the one you already mentioned: fiddle with the source and remove the tab